# To make group by predictions using test & train data, group by multiple columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Am very new to machine learning, and alogirithms.  Am learning the various ml concepts, so please excuse for my ignorance.

I am working on a project, wherein I need to make a prediction for sales rep calls to be made for the future quarter, based on the rep_calls in the last historic data.  Am providing herewith a sample dataframe for your reference and to provide suggestions please.

The rep_calls prediction for QTR4, should be based on the rep calls for the CUSTOMER_NUMBER & PRODUCT_ID, that is available for the last 3 quarter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CUSTOMER_NUMBER": ["CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST1", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST2", "CUST3", "CUST3", "CUST3", "CUST4", "CUST4", "CUST4"],
"PRODUCT": ["PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT3", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2"],
"REP_VISITS": ["3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "4", "6", "8", "5", "3", "1", "3", "2", "0", "3"],
"QTR": ["QTR1", "QTR1", "QTR1", "QTR2", "QTR2", "QTR2", "QTR3", "QTR3", "QTR3", "QTR1", "QTR1", "QTR1", "QTR2", "QTR2", "QTR2", "QTR3", "QTR1", "QTR2", "QTR3", "QTR1", "QTR2", "QTR3"],
"START_DATE": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-04-01",  "2020-04-01", "2020-04-01","2020-07-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-07-01"],
"END_DATE": ["2020-03-31", "2020-03-31", "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-06-30", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-03-31", "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-06-30", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30"]})
```

The dataframe looks as below:

[image]

I need to find out the predicted rep_calls for QTR4.

```
CUST1|PRODUCT1||QTR4|
CUST1|PRODUCT2||QTR4|
CUST1|PRODUCT3||QTR4|
CUST2|PRODUCT1||QTR4|
CUST2|PRODUCT2||QTR4|
CUST2|PRODUCT3||QTR4|
CUST3|PRODUCT3||QTR4|
CUST4|PRODUCT1||QTR4|
CUST4|PRODUCT2||QTR4|
```

Please guide me how i can create training dataset for customers/products, with appopriate predictions, so i can use the test_data for predictions/valuations.

Comment: Sorry Yuva, I think we need a more detailed description of the problem. Which variable has to be predicted from the table you showed? REP_VISITS? and what variables you have that you can use for prediction? If you only have the variables you are showing I see no big potential for machine learning here, you are better off with some statistics, curve modelling.

Comment: Thanks Lucas Ramos. Yes I need to predict the REP VISITs for the upcoming quarter, say Qtr4. What could be possible approach, if machine learning isn't required for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try using customer no. and product id as features and train a simple classifier using Logistic Regression or decision trees. You could try using 1-hot encoding for different customer numbers and product ID's. If you are trying this approach, REP_visits could be the labels and the features could be cust1, cust2,cust3, product1, product2, etc.
scikitlearn has implementations of these algorithms, which are easy to use. Hope this helps:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
unique_cust_nos = df['CUSTOMER_NUMBER'].unique()
unique_products = df['PRODUCT'].unique()
features = []
for item in unique_cust_nos:
    features.append(item)
for item in unique_products:
    features.append(item)
for idx, item in df.iterrows():
#     make a dataframe(all_features_df) so that ['CUST1', 'CUST2', 'CUST3', 'CUST4', 'PRODUCT1', 'PRODUCT2', 'PRODUCT3'] are feature columns and rep_visits is the label
X = all_features_df[feature_cols] # Features
y = all_features_df[label] # Target variable
# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X,y)
#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thank you Shaista, would it be possible to share code snippets, as am new to machine learning, beginner and trying to understand various algos.  The same code would help me understand your response.  Appreciate if you can.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, meantime can you please confirm if X_test in your sample code would be my dataset for QTR4? as a dataframe, because i dont see any assignment for X_test? Thanks

Comment: Yes, X_test would be the features for QTR4.

Comment: hi can you please help me with the dataframe all_features_df creation, in the sample code,  Also, i dont see if features dataframe is used anywhere, is it required.  Thanks